# .htaccess: disable easter eggs over .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to disable all PHP easter eggs like this:

```
www.example.com/?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000
```

I added this code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This works for `http://www.example.com/?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000` but not for `https://www.example.com/?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000`, means it works for `http://` but not for `https://`.

I additionally added this in `.htaccess` to redirect all `https://` to `http://`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But it's still not working. The easter egg ist still accessible from `https://www.example.com/?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000`.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I don't have access to `php.ini` to set it up there.

Comment: Are you also unable to override ini settings via your .htaccess? try adding this to .htaccess if you are unsure: `php_value expose_php 0`

Comment: @TheoTonge `php_value expose_php 0` makes `Internal Server Error` for my whole domain.

Comment: sounds like you aren't allowed to do this then - see my answer below (otherwise this may be a restriction on your server - as this requires `AllowOverride All` adding to your apache config)

Comment: Make sure `VirtualHost` entry for `SSL` is pointing to same `DocumentRoot` as non-SSL one.

Comment: @anubhava How can I check this? Can I force this with `.htaccess`?

Comment: No, that is done on Apache server side.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine on` must come before any rules.

any conditions listed apply to the next rule.
by adding the L flag to a rule, you prevent it from checking any more rules

from the docs:

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

So try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Apologies, I had not fully read/understood your issue - I have now corrected my answer, hopefully this solves for you!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately still the same, not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need an equals character here... STRING} =PHP ...should then work okay. d:o)

Comment: The space before the equal character and the absence of a space after matter.  The entire string should be...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bigger picture...

```
### If mod_rewrite is true...
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
### Prevent Apache from showing its server signature...
ServerSignature off
### Prevent phpinfo from showing details...
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =PHP[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12} [NC] RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

...paste into your .htaccess file. The space} =PHP before the equal character and the absence of a space thereafter matter.  d:o)